# Laravel Mix: Extracting a non-npm vendor file

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I was wondering if it was possible to extract vendor files that aren't part of node_modules.

I have code similar to the following but obviously, it doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['jquery', 'resources/assets/vendor/redactor/redactor.min.js'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract non-npm vendor files from your javascript file.